# React: Script validation

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

So I have a component which renders two 360 images. The component is almost done but there are two things left to be done which I can't get my head around.

So here is the block of code that mounts the scripts:

```
componentDidMount() {

    if(this.threesixty_interior){
        const s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'source/player.js';
        s.dataset.interior = true;
        s.dataset.subject = this.props.subject;
        this.threesixty_interior.appendChild(s);
    }

    if(this.threesixty_exterior){
        const s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'source/player.js';
        s.dataset.exterior = true;
        s.dataset.subject = this.props.subject;
        this.threesixty_exterior.appendChild(s);
    }
}
```

And this is how I render them:

```
render() {
    return(
    <div className="player">
        <div ref={el => (this.threesixty_interior = el)} />
        <div ref={el => (this.threesixty_exterior = el)} />
    </div>
    )
}
```

So what I want to do is the following.
I have a child component where I play a loading animation. So I want to simply check if both scripts mounted properly and remove that loading animation. 
How do I do that?? 
Is this is even a good approach for calling scripts inside your react app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone viewing this question, the [react-script-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-script-tag) package solved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not good idea load script in componentWillMount() or componentDidMount(). See more about lifecycle [here](https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1). 
You can use [react-load-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-load-script) package. It simplifies loading of 3rd party scripts in your React applications.

Example:

```
import Script from 'react-load-script'

...

render() {
  return (
    <Script
      url="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"
      attributes={{id: 'someId', 'data-custom: 'value'}}
      onCreate={this.handleScriptCreate.bind(this)}
      onError={this.handleScriptError.bind(this)}
      onLoad={this.handleScriptLoad.bind(this)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Hello. I tried your approach. Well it works but in a very weird way. I am not sure you fully understood my question but what I am trying to do is to call a player which plays some 360 images. So when I visit the page where the script should execute, it does and everything works fine, but then I can see it on every singe page of my app.